# How do Python developers deal with moving directories in projects that contain a lot of strings that are paths to other parts of the project?

Tags: python, path, pycharm

I am doing a project that contains a lot of modules and directories. In my modules a lot of times I use strings that are paths to other files in another directory. I was wondering if there is an easy way of refactoring these strings when moving directories. For example, In one module i have the following code: `pd.read_pickle("C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\foo\df.pkl")`. When I move the "foo" directory to another directory I want this string and all others that lead to "foo" to be changed to the new path. Pycharm is the IDE I'm using. Does it have something that does something similar? Or are there other ways I can acomplish this with ease?

I tried to look for similar questions but didn't find any.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So Chat GPT gave me the following answer:

Yes, PyCharm has a feature that can help with this called "Relative Paths". You can use relative paths to specify the location of a file relative to the location of the script that is using it, rather than using absolute paths. This allows you to move the files around without having to update the paths in your code.

To use relative paths in PyCharm, you first need to create a project. Then, in your code, you can use the os.path module to specify the relative path to the file. For example:

```
import os
file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..", "foo", "df.pkl")
df = pd.read_pickle(file_path)
```

This will use the location of the script that is executing the code as a starting point and navigate to the "foo" directory to find the file. This way, if you move the "foo" directory, you only need to update the relative path in one place, rather than searching through your code for all instances of the absolute path.

Comment: Please see the announcement on the usage of ChatGPT: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned